# Cannot find a differ supporting object in Angular

Tags: angular, http-get

I've been trying to display data from a web api but i got an error when iterating to display them.

Here's is a copy of my component file.

```
this.uploadService.getFiles()
    .subscribe(
          data => this.files$ = data 
     );
```

HTML COMPONENT FILE:

```
<a *ngFor="let file of files$"  class="list-group-item list- 
    group-item-action">{{file.id}}</a>`
```

THE WEBAPI JSON FILE:

```
[{"Id":458,"FileCode":609"},{"Id":451,"FileCode":602"}]
```

THE SERVICE FILE:

```
public getFiles(){
    return this.httpClient.get(this.SERVER_URLGETFILE)
}
```

The error message i got is "Cannot find a differ supporting object []NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Comment: Cannot find a differ supporting object, is telling you that you are trying to use an object in the *ngFor. Are you sure your api is returning an Array ?

Comment: I included the value that my API is returning.

Answer (score 0):

initialize your files$ like this:

```
files$ : any = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
this.uploadService.getFiles()
    .subscribe(
          data: any[] => this.files$[] = data 
     );
```